# Run docker without host OS?

Tags: docker

Is it possible that I run docker without any host OS. I mean run it natively. It would be a performance boost that way I believe if possible.

Suppose I have a tool which runs on linux kernel. I create a docker container with some extra dependencies. Now I share that container with other person who has linux to run that container.

But I want to run that container without host OS. as it will be double layer of OS with container.

Comment: Docker already shares the same kernel used by the host, unless you're using Docker Machine or some equivalent. You can't go from two kernels to one because it's already just one kernel; the overhead you're asking us how to get rid of doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: Ok. so what if host OS is windows and docker container is linux?

Comment: Then Docker Machine starts up one (exactly one) Linux VM, and uses that VM's kernel for all your containers, no matter how many you have. There's still only exactly one Linux kernel, so there's no room to optimize further.

Comment: But that will still run on top of windows? am I right?

Comment: Right. If you want to have only one kernel, your host needs to be Linux. That's still different from "without [any] host OS", as this question asks for.

Comment: You would need an OS. The best would be to have a lean OS. Few options that could explore in that case is alpine + docker, rancher os, core os.

Comment: You could use the [scratch](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/) base image in your Dockerfile, depending on what you needed to run. This works for some golang apps. For instance: https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Docker itself is not a VM, so there is no double layer of OS. Docker is a tool to run applications with settings that isolate them from other applications running on the same OS kernel. Docker does include a VM with Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac to run the Linux kernel so you can run Linux containers. There is an option to run native Windows containers with Server 2016, but if you are looking for minimal and efficiency, I would suggest looking elsewhere.

The closest things to what you are looking for are:

- Unikernels: these are applications compiled into a kernel with everything else removed, designed to run inside of a VM for a very specialized task, often security related. These are still early in their development stage, but Docker does use some of their technology inside their project.
- LinuxKit (part of the Moby Project): this is how Docker creates their VMs for Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac. It is a container based Linux operating system that you can custom compile with only the containers you want to run. Most of the focus of this is still designed for VMs, but bare metal is an option.
- Scratch base image: if you statically compile your application to remove all of the library dependencies, you can have a container without any shell or other OS tools. This is often seen in Go binaries shipped as Docker containers to do a single task with a very small attack surface. As a Docker container, it still requires the underlying Linux OS to run the binary.