# Are there OS implemenations that support Docker without the overhead of a "all bells and wistles" OS like windows, mac or linux

Tags: docker, operating-system, self-hosting

I know running a docker image witout an OS is not possible.

I have an old PC just standing in the closet and I want to use this for 100% docker hosting(as development server). The machine has 4x500GB of diskspace so it would be a waste not using it, even when its HDD instead of SDD

What are my options in this case? Are their OS availble with minimal overhead when it comes to resources.

My requirements are

1. I can still configure the OS itself(drivers, printers, ...) by running a (remote) configuration tool(and control using either remote or keybaord/screen attached)
2. Has minimal overhead when NOT using the configuration tool to maximoze the resources I can assign to images.
3. free or minimal expesense to purchase

The ultimate goal is to be able to host en entire newtwork of applications on a single machine during development (inluding DB) without losing 20GB of diskspace just for an OS I will barely be using by itself besides adding/removing images.

I found this answer but I don't feel like its a perfect match since I don't want "without host OS" but with minimal host OS

[Run docker without host OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285198/run-docker-without-host-os)

I'm not expecting a list of OS implementations, but rather a list of "here you find more info on the subject" sugeestions to get me started.

Comment: Docker generally requires a Linux kernel and I'd start there.  This isn't really about programming at all, and somewhere like [unix.se] might be more appropriate to ask, though [their rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) also seem to discourage "what is the best..." type questions.